# Rank rows within grouped by (2 columns)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have written a query to get data like this (attached image), user_id and topic_id is grouped and the average of the score is calculated. I want to rank the score for each user, so each user has rank 1 for their highest topic_id. How can we write query to rank their scores, because I need to select the top row for each user.

Table looks like this -

```
USER_ID        TOPIC_ID    SCORE  
------------- ------------- ------ 
 b33e3100a7be  829e4b89c318  85     
 b33e3100a7be  b19b6f2b2975  82     
 b33e3100a7be  e305c970701c  81.6   
 b33e3100a7be  6c6fac161e65  81.6   
 7379ce6bc5a9  6c6fac161e65  54.6   
 7379ce6bc5a9  e305c970701c  54.6   
 7379ce6bc5a9  b19b6f2b2975  51.6
```

and want output look like this.

```
 USER_ID        TOPIC_ID    SCORE  RANK
------------- ------------- ------ -----
 b33e3100a7be  829e4b89c318  85     1
 b33e3100a7be  b19b6f2b2975  82     2
 b33e3100a7be  e305c970701c  81.6   3
 b33e3100a7be  6c6fac161e65  81.6   3
 7379ce6bc5a9  6c6fac161e65  54.6   1
 7379ce6bc5a9  e305c970701c  54.6   1
 7379ce6bc5a9  b19b6f2b2975  54.6   2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnzGi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest-score row per use with  `distinct on` :

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from mytable t
order by user_id, score desc
```

It is likely that we could further optimize the code if you were to show the data you are *starting with*, and the query you used to generate the intermediate resultset you are showing. You might want to ask a new question for this, providing proper sample data, desired results and existing code.

If you want to allow ties, then you can use `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by user_id order by score desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Or, in Postgres 13:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by rank() over(partition by user_id order by score desc)
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Comment: I have edited the question, sample table and output added to it.

Comment: But if user has 2 different topics, and both have same score, and they are the top two rows for that user, I need both rows not one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to get all the top scores:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by user_id order by score desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In this context, `rank()` returns all the highest topics, if there is a tie.  `row_number()` returns one arbitrarily.

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score = (select max(t2.score)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.user_id = t.user_id
                );
```

Note that both of these methods can be incorporated into an aggregation query.  There is not need to save intermediate results to get what you want.